# JQuery UI: dropping an item out of Sortable on a non-Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I've got two Sortable lists, with the right one connected to the left one. I want to be able to remove items from the left list, by dropping them on a trash box. I'm trying to implement the trash box as a Droppable, but on the ´drop´ event of the Droppable the Sortable still contains all of the items. This way, if I iterate on the Sortable's ´ul´ children I still encounter the item that I'm dropping.

Is there a way to get the updated list of items in the Sortable?

Comment: what if you just remove the droped item' html, using js?

Comment: @Suleman, how does this affect the Sortable? I hope to find out whether there's an event I should use instead of `drop`, or if there's a "safe" way to remove the item from the Sortable - is abruptly removing the `li` ok?

Comment: you need to refresh the sortable list, so that list re-binds with new data.

Comment: Please accept the asnwer, if this solution works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery UI: Sortable cache the contents at client side for super fasting sorting. So whenever removing any element, then need to rebind the list again so that cache is refreshed.

Comment: I'll add that the dropped item is passed to the `drop` event handler as the second parameter. You can get the HTML element with the `draggable` property.